# How to check whether Python code raised any exceptions

Tags: python

I want to test that a large chunk of Python code doesn't raise any exceptions. Both because they're a bit expensive so I want to avoid them under "normal" execution, and because I want my debugger's ability to break on any raised exception to pinpoint the earliest sign of something going wrong.

I can manually run this code with the debugger to test that my code is free of raised exeptions, but I'd like to automate this to avoid regressions.

I tried to use [`sys.settrace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace), but I keep observing `"exception"` events. I suspect they happen deep inside Python library code and the debugger ignores those. Should I attempt to filter out only the exceptions in my code? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Are you talking about uncaught exceptions raised from that code, or exceptions that are caught within it?  The former is something you get for free with any kind of testing, and the latter doesn't make sense as something to prevent.

Comment: @Samwise I'm talking about caught exceptions. I'm working on a large and complex library and when debugging it with breaking on each raised exception enabled I found several instances of unexpected exceptions that only through luck hadn't caused real harm yet.

Comment: That sounds like a problem that's better caught through static analysis -- it could be as simple as grepping for `except:` and `except Exception` since most of your errors probably match one of those.  In well-written code it's perfectly normal to catch and handle specific exceptions but it sounds like you might be dealing with `except: pass` kind of stuff that newer programmers might do to try to "fix" their bugs by making them harder to find.

Comment: My concern is not about how exceptions are caught and handled. I need to verify programmatically that none get **raised** under normal circumstances, both to facilitate debugging and to optimize performance.

Comment: If exceptions aren't being caught incorrectly, then it's trivial to verify that your code doesn't raise uncaught exceptions: just call it.
If the code is catching exceptions that it shouldn't, such that they don't raise out of the code when there's a problem, that goes back to static analysis, because your code should not do that (and it's pretty easy to prevent by following standard coding practices).